# Clicking element in IE devtools fixes IE layout bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have some text in a Flexbox layout that does not appear in IE11 (the parent elements have a computed height of 0px).

If, in IE's "DOM Explorer", I click on the div element that directly contains the text, **then the text suddenly appears!**

This only happens if the tab on the right of the inspector is set to "Styles" or "Computed" – clicking on the div with another tab open ("Layout", "Events"…) does not cause the text to appear.

The text displays as expected without intervention in other modern browsers.

I presume that some sort of style recalculation is happening when I inspect the element, which fixes the display issue. Is there some way to trigger a similar event from JavaScript, or otherwise work around the issue?

Comment: Do you have a demo, it would be easier to help debug.
 
I would also suggest checking out this list of known flexbox bugs and fixes you might find a solution in there. https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in my case was that I was setting a parent element's data attribute with `elem.dataset`, which does not behave correctly in IE (see IE bug 1104713, marked WONTFIX a year ago).

The workaround is to use `elem.setAttribute`, which correctly updates psuedo-elements.